# DbContext cannot be used because it's being disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

First off all, I have searched already but didn't come up with a solution because I believe my problem is a bit different.

I have a UnitOfWork and I'm using Unity Dependency Injection for resolving the instances of the container.

I have an UnitOfWork which implements an IUnitOfWork.
This UnitOfWork has 3 different constructors:

```
public UnitOfWork()
    : this(new UnitOfSettings(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host))
{
}

public UnitOfWork(DbContext settingsEntities)
    : this(new UnitOfSettings(settingsEntities, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host))
{
}

public UnitOfWork(UnitOfSettings unitOfSettings)
{
    // Logic left out to made it clear.
}
```

Also, this class has a lot of repositories object. Those are not listed here because I don't think they add any value.

So, now I have Unity that registers the interfaces:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new SettingsEntities()));
}
```

Since I resolve my IUnitOfWork with a new SettingsEntities, I've also registered the SettingsEntities in the container. The SettingsEntities is a DbContext (Entity Framework - Model first).

But, I when accessing the repository through the unit of work, I still receive the error message:

“The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.”

I don't know what's going on here since I'm using the PerRequestLifetimeManager.

The error is happening in the constructor chaining of the UnitOfWork.
Probably because I'm constructor a new UnitOfSettings rather than resolving it through the dependency injector. Could that be the cause, and is there an elegant way to solve it?

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: I've updated the question since it's not the controller action but the constructor chaining which fails.

Comment: @Complexity which particular constructor is being called when you get the error? Where is `DbContext settingsEntities` instantiated?

Comment: I'll review. You ask this because the context must be created through the Unity container. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @Complexity the `DbContext` doesn't need to be created by the `container` but I'm wondering what else could be calling `Dispose()` on the `DbContext`.

Comment: Tip: override `Dispose(bool)` in your DbContext implementation and set a break point. That will allow you to find out directly where it is disposed. Just look at the stack trace in the debugger.

Comment: btw, what the hell is that call to `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` doing inside the `IUnitOfWork` registration? Don't do that. As a matter of fact, don't use auto-wiring on your DbContext at all. [Framework types should not be auto-wired](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97#Framework-types).

Comment: I've changed my code to get rid of the GetService so that's already solved. And I've checked my code and the iUnitOfWork is disposable, but the dispose method is only called in the UnitOfWork, so as far as I can see, the iUnitOfWork is not disposed by some other code.

Comment: The callstack shows me that the context is disposed by external code, but I have in fact 2 unit of works (UnitOfWork & UnitOfSettings) and in the UnitOfWork, when its disposed the context is away. Any advice on how to solve?